# How ReactJS interacts with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, jsx

Recently I've decided to try ReactJS for UI in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Everything looks more or less clear except the way how I should interact with controllers from/to JSX files and how should I pass data between them.

I've read different SO topics about this but found that almost everyone goes with some kind of unique way of doing that.

**So, here is my questions**: Should I make all my ASP.NET endpoints so that they return Json(model) instead of ASP.NET View() and use fetch/http-requests on ReactJS side to communicate with app?

Or is there a way to pass a model/data from a controller to JSX files from a view without changing controller actions behaviour (for example I want to leave «as is» my current return View(model) behaviour)?

Thank you!

Comment: A view is for returning HTML. If you have a SPA app, those typically consume JSON, not HTML. So a view wouldn't be an appropriate thing to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture really depends on your requirements, which are not specified here. I would recommend going with the separation of the front-end(ReactJS SPA) and back-end(ASP NET Core WebAPI) with communication via http protocol.
If you have to stick to ASP Net MVC you can take a look on this library: https://reactjs.net/